# How to receive an update notification when a user enables 2-step verification?

Tags: python, google-admin-sdk

I have created a channel to send my app notifications when a user is updated like so:

```
data = {
    'id': channel_id,
    'type': 'web_hook',
    'address': domain_address,
    'kind': 'api#channel',
}
channel = directory.users().watch(body=data, domain=my_domain, event='update').execute()
```

This successfully sends notifications when I update the user in the Admin SDK GUI. However, when a user takes an action that causes their information to update, such as logging in, changing their password or enabling 2-step verification, I receive no notification.

My end goal is to receive a notification when a user enables 2-step verification, i.e. when the `isEnrolledIn2Sv` attribute changes from `False` to `True`. Is there any way of doing this?

Thank you!

EDIT: The workaround I used was to create a webhook (I used AWS Lambda) to query all users known to have the `isEnrolledIn2Sv` attribute set to `False`, and see if any had changed to `True`. It works! But not ideal, so would love to hear if anyone else knows a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: You may want to use the [`Users: watch`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/watch) which watches for changes in users list. You may also check the [Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/push) which provides push notifications that let you watch for changes to resources. Currently, the Directory API supports notifications for changes to the [Users](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/watch) resource.

Comment: I believe that's what I have set up here - it calls the watch command on the users resource on the directory API. Did I not do it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to 'update', it looks like you want to request 'add' events, as well.